# Replace values in one column with randomly generated values using group_by and mutate, while making sure every set of values is unique in R

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

I am writing a function to replace ID's in one column with randomly generated ones. Suppose I have a dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3), Name = c("Joseph", "Joseph", "Leo", "Leo", "Joseph", "David"))
```

```
  ID   Name
1  1 Joseph
2  1 Joseph
3  2    Leo
4  2    Leo
5  1 Joseph
6  3  David
```

The goal of the function is to group the dataset by ID and replace all unique ID's with randomly generated ones, like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

generateRandomString <- function() {
    sample(LETTERS, 1)
}
replaceUniqueID <- function(data, column_id) {
  name.id <- data[grep(column_id, colnames(data))]
  data.new <- data %>%
      group_by(data[grep(column_id, colnames(data))]) %>% 
      mutate_at(column_id, funs(generateRandomString()))
data.new
}

replaceUniqueID(df, "ID")

# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID    Name  
  <chr> <chr> 
1 D     Joseph
2 D     Joseph
3 R     Leo   
4 R     Leo   
5 D     Joseph
6 Q     David
```

My problem is, I want the code to make sure every ID gets replaced with unique string, e.g. `David` and `Leo` can't both have `D` as a replacement for their respective ID's.

I tried to come up with an `ifelse` statement within `mutate` but was unable to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a translation dictionary to solve this relatively easily.

```r
genRandomIDs <- function(ID, min_length = 2) {
  ID <- unique(ID)
  len <- max(min_length, length(ID) %/% 26 + 1)
  ltrs <- do.call(paste0,
    do.call(expand.grid, replicate(len, LETTERS, simplify=FALSE))
  )
  sample(ltrs, length(ID))
}
set.seed(42)
IDdict <- df %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  mutate(newID = genRandomIDs(ID))
IDdict
#   ID newID
# 1  1    OV
# 2  2    IM
# 3  3    WF
df %>%
  left_join(IDdict, by = "ID")
#   ID   Name newID
# 1  1 Joseph    OV
# 2  1 Joseph    OV
# 3  2    Leo    IM
# 4  2    Leo    IM
# 5  1 Joseph    OV
# 6  3  David    WF
```

Walk-through:

- `genRandomIDs` is just a helper function that internally produces a vector of all `n`-long letter permutations (combined with `paste0`) and samples from them;

  - the `do.call(expand.grid, ...)` gives us a frame that expands on each `len` grouping of letters; that is, `expand.grid(LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[1:3])` gives us `3^3` permutations of three letters
  - the `do.call(paste0, ...)` takes that frame from `expand.grid` (which is really just a glorified `list`) and produces one string per "row".
- `distinct(ID)` reduces your `df` to just one row per `ID`;
- since we produce one `newID` for each unique `ID`, we now have a 1-to-1 mapping from old-to-new;
- the `left_join` assigns the `newID` for each row (if you aren't familiar with merges/joins, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272))

Note: this does not really scale well: since we explode the possible combinations with `expand.grid`, for a min-length of 2 letters, we produce 676 (`26^2`) permutations, not a problem. `26^3` produces 17576 possible combinations, whether or not we have that many IDs to uniquify. `26^4` (4 letters) produces 456976, and its delay is "palpable". Five letters is over 11 million, which becomes "stupid" to try to scale to that length (assuming you have that many unique `ID`s or choose a string of that long.

*However* ... while inefficient, this method is guaranteed to give you unique `newID`s. There are other ways that may be guaranteed at the expense of a (however small) increase in complexity).

---

Okay, the "increased complexity" here for a more efficient process:

```r
num2alpha <- function(num, chr = letters, zero = "", sep = "") {
  len <- length(chr)
  stopifnot(len > 1)
  signs <- ifelse(!is.na(num) & sign(num) < 0, "-", "")
  num <- as.integer(abs(num))
  is0 <- !is.na(num) & num < 1e-9
  # num[num < 1] <- NA
  out <- character(length(num))
  mult <- 0
  while (any(!is.na(num) & num > 0)) {
    not0 <- !is.na(num) & num > 0
    out[not0] <- paste0(chr[(num[not0] - 1) %% len + 1], sep, out[not0])
    num[not0] <- (num[not0] - 1) %/% len
  }
  if (nzchar(sep)) out <- sub(paste0(sep, "$"), "", out)
  out[is0] <- zero
  out[is.na(num)] <- NA
  out[!is.na(out)] <- paste0(signs[!is.na(out)], out[!is.na(out)])
  out
}

IDdict <- df %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  mutate(newID = num2alpha(row_number()))
IDdict
#   ID newID
# 1  1     a
# 2  2     b
# 3  3     c
df %>%
  left_join(IDdict, by = "ID")
#   ID   Name newID
# 1  1 Joseph     a
# 2  1 Joseph     a
# 3  2    Leo     b
# 4  2    Leo     b
# 5  1 Joseph     a
# 6  3  David     c
```

The `num2alpha` works more efficiently (using lower-case here, easily changed by using `num2alpha(.., chr=LETTERS)`), though it is deterministic here. If you are at all concerned about that, then

```r
IDdict <- df %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  mutate(newID = sample(num2alpha(row_number())))
```

will randomize them for you.

Note that this produces single-letter strings up through 26, then cycles through 2-digit and 3-digit. It also recognized negatives, and while the defatul

```r
num2alpha(c(-5, 0, NA, 1, 25:27, 51:53, 999999), zero="0")
#  [1] "-e"    "0"     NA      "a"     "y"     "z"     "aa"    "ay"    "az"    "ba"    "bdwgm"
```

(Note that this is not a simple base-converter, since we're ignoring "0"-values. Try `num2alpha(14:16, c(1:9, LETTERS[1:6]), zero="0")`. Perhaps it can be made to be more general.)

Comment: That certainly works, but I might indeed require large amounts of strings, so it would be great to have the code produce 4 or 5 letter (or a combination of letters and numbers) strings. What would be a way to accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: @Makie, I edited (_again_) an efficient version of `num2alpha` that does the new-ID generation efficiently, regardless of the length. Hope it helps!