# Assign a letter to each name in R to deidentify a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

I have seen many posts regarding using the letters function in R to assign a letter ID to a row number, however my question is a bit different from that- I am looking to deidentify a dataset and would like to assign a letter to each clinician, some of whom appear in the dataset multiple times, and they have that same letter through the dataset.

For example, I want to make a column called "letter" that looks like this:

[image]

How would I add on that second letter column based on names from the first column? Here is some dput to play around with:

```
DF<-data.frame(ProviderID=c("Harry Potter","Hermione Granger","Ron Weasley", "Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing to guard against using letters is if you have more than 26 providers. Options: if there are 52 or fewer providers, then `c(LETTERS, letters)` may suffice; add another 10 with `c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9)`; or go with [`num2alpha`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76248063/3358272) for an arbitrary number-to-multi-letters solution.

```r
num2alpha <- function(num, chr = letters, zero = "", sep = "") {
  len <- length(chr)
  stopifnot(len > 1)
  signs <- ifelse(!is.na(num) & sign(num) < 0, "-", "")
  num <- as.integer(abs(num))
  is0 <- !is.na(num) & num < 1e-9
  # num[num < 1] <- NA
  out <- character(length(num))
  mult <- 0
  while (any(!is.na(num) & num > 0)) {
    not0 <- !is.na(num) & num > 0
    out[not0] <- paste0(chr[(num[not0] - 1) %% len + 1], sep, out[not0])
    num[not0] <- (num[not0] - 1) %/% len
  }
  if (nzchar(sep)) out <- sub(paste0(sep, "$"), "", out)
  out[is0] <- zero
  out[is.na(num)] <- NA
  out[!is.na(out)] <- paste0(signs[!is.na(out)], out[!is.na(out)])
  out
}
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(DF)[, letter := num2alpha(match(ProviderID, unique(ProviderID)))]
#          ProviderID letter
#              <char> <char>
# 1:     Harry Potter      a
# 2: Hermione Granger      b
# 3:      Ron Weasley      c
# 4:     Harry Potter      a
# 5: Hermione Granger      b
```

You can use upper-case with `chr=`:

```r
as.data.table(DF)[, letter := num2alpha(match(ProviderID, unique(ProviderID)), chr = LETTERS)]
#          ProviderID letter
#              <char> <char>
# 1:     Harry Potter      A
# 2: Hermione Granger      B
# 3:      Ron Weasley      C
# 4:     Harry Potter      A
# 5: Hermione Granger      B
```

I think the use of `rleid` here is ill-advised, as `Harry Potter` on non-consecutive rows will present different `letter`s.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate(letter = num2alpha(match(ProviderID, unique(ProviderID))))
```

## base R

```r
DF$letter <- num2alpha(match(DF$ProviderID, unique(DF$ProviderID)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% mutate(row=row_number()) %>% arrange(ProviderID) %>% 
  mutate(ids=data.table::rleid(ProviderID),
         letters=LETTERS[ids]) %>% 
  arrange(row) %>% select(-c(row,ids))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
        ProviderID letters
1     Harry Potter       A
2 Hermione Granger       B
3      Ron Weasley       C
4     Harry Potter       A
5 Hermione Granger       B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `match`

```
> transform(DF,letter = LETTERS[match(ProviderID, unique(ProviderID))])
        ProviderID letter
1     Harry Potter      A
2 Hermione Granger      B
3      Ron Weasley      C
4     Harry Potter      A
5 Hermione Granger      B
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the forcats package from the tidyverse, you can assign numbers to the names as a first step. You could then replace them by letters – or by combinations of letters, similar to what r2evans suggested.

If you can rule out that there are more than 26 distinct names in your data, you can simply use `LETTERS` instead of `c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters))` below.

```r
library(forcats)

DF<-data.frame(ProviderID=c("Harry Potter","Hermione Granger","Ron Weasley", "Harry Potter", "Hermione Granger"))

# Count distinct names:
length(unique(DF$ProviderID))
#> [1] 3

# Assign a number to each name:
DF$Letter <- DF$ProviderID %>% 
    fct_anon() %>% 
    as.character()

# Replace the numbers by letters:
for (i in seq_along(DF$Letter)) {
    DF$Letter[i] <- c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters))[i]
}

DF
#>         ProviderID Letter
#> 1     Harry Potter      A
#> 2 Hermione Granger      B
#> 3      Ron Weasley      C
#> 4     Harry Potter      D
#> 5 Hermione Granger      E
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

r2evans gave a variety of good options in different packages.  You could also do this with data.table without a writing a new function:

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(DF)
IDlist<-DT[, .(ProviderID =unique(ProviderID), Letters=(LETTERS[1:length(unique(ProviderID))])) ]
DT<-IDlist[DT, on="ProviderID"] #   #Adds the Coded ID
```

to give:

```
> DT
         ProviderID Letters
1:     Harry Potter       A
2: Hermione Granger       B
3:      Ron Weasley       C
4:     Harry Potter       A
5: Hermione Granger       B
```

If the intent is to code the provider ID for blinding/masking, a few more lines will do this, too.  With a couple of data columns added as an example:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(6502)
DT<-data.table(DF)
DT[ , `:=`(Data1=runif(5, 20, 50), Data2=runif(5, 100,500))]    #  Add some data to your table
#   Make a table linking each provider with a randomly assigned letter.  This can be saved for later use.
IDlist<-DT[, .(ProviderID =unique(ProviderID), CodedID=(sample(LETTERS[1:length(unique(ProviderID))], length(unique(ProviderID))))) ]
DT<-IDlist[DT, on="ProviderID"] #   #Adds the Coded ID
DT[, ProviderID:=NULL]          #  Remove unblinded ID
```

Yielding:

```
> DT
   CodedID    Data1    Data2
1:       A 38.71399 178.8384
2:       C 45.32531 434.8654
3:       B 32.67079 420.2604
4:       A 22.49274 376.1324
5:       C 37.50478 369.3482
```

Comment: fyi, don't use `require` this way, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path. Use `library(data.table)` or `if (!require(data.table)) { do_something_here(); }`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out with the explanatory link.  I've updated the code block.